# kendo editor is not working inside kendo tab strip

Tags: kendo-ui

I have use a kendo tab strip and inside it i have use editor, my editor is 
display but it's not working, when i try to write in editor can't write..
I have check in console but there is no any error..
please solve this issue
Code:-

```
<div id="edit">
            <ul>
                <li >
                    Info      <--tab 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Date      <-- Tab 2
                </li>
                <li class="k-state-active">
                    Document   <- tab 3 editor tab
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
<div style="height:500px;">
                <div>
                     fsdfsdf
                </div>

            </div>
            <div style="height:500px;">

                <div>
                    dffsdf
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="height:500px;">

                <div>
                    <div id="example">
    <textarea id="Description" rows="10" cols="30" style="width:100%;height:400px"></textarea>
</div>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Description").kendoEditor({
            tools: [

                "insertImage",
                        "insertFile",
    ],
    });
    });
    </script>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Works for me...you need to provide a jsFiddle or some other reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for me, and i found that it's because your html structure. After i fix it and add tabstrip then the kendo editor it works fine.

I change your html to :

```
 <div id="edit">
        <ul>
            <li >
                Info      <--tab 1
            </li>
            <li>
                Date      <-- Tab 2
            </li>
            <li class="k-state-active">
                Document   <- tab 3 editor tab
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div style="height:500px;">
            <div>
                 fsdfsdf
            </div>

        </div>
        <div style="height:500px;">
            <div>
                dffsdf
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="height:500px;">
            <div>
                <div id="example">
                    <textarea id="Description" rows="10" cols="30" style="width:100%;height:400px">          </textarea>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Then the js code :

```
<script>
       $("#edit").kendoTabStrip({
         animation:  {
           open: {
             effects: "fadeIn"
           }
         }
       });
       $("#Description").kendoEditor({
            tools: [
                    "insertImage",
                        "insertFile",
                    ],
       });
</script>
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/aZAto)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by simply initializing kendoTabStrip before initializing KendoEditor. 
BTW: I found kendoTabStrip is quite problematic. I mean, the box-sizing, z-index are all coded to behave oddly.